# Inlining ECMAScript Modules in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've been experimenting with new [native ECMAScript module support](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) that has recently been added to browsers. It's pleasant to finally be able import scripts directly and cleanly from JavaScript.

[**`/example.html`**](https://795258201.glitch.me/example.html)

```html
<script type="module">
  import {example} from '/example.js';

  example();
</script>
```

[**`/example.js`**](https://795258201.glitch.me/example.js)

```js
export function example() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
};
```

However, this only allows me to import modules that are defined by separate **external** JavaScript files. I usually prefer to inline some scripts used for the initial rendering, so their requests don't block the rest of the page. With a traditional informally-structured library, that might look like this:

[**`/inline-traditional.html`**](https://795258201.glitch.me/inline-traditional.html)

```html
<body>
<script>
  var example = {};

  example.example = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
  };
</script>
<script>
  example.example();
</script>
```

However, naively inlining modules files obviously won't work, since it would remove the filename used to identify the module to other modules. HTTP/2 server push may be the canonical way to handle this situation, but it's still not an option in all environments.

Is it possible to perform an equivalent transformation with ECMAScript modules?

Is there any way for a `<script type="module">` to import a module exported by another in the same document?

---

I imagine this could work by allowing the script to specify a file path, and behave as though it had already been downloaded or pushed from the path.

[**`/inline-name.html`**](https://795258201.glitch.me/inline-name.html)

```html
<script type="module" name="/example.js">
  export function example() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
  };
</script>

<script type="module">
  import {example} from '/example.js';

  example();
</script>
```

Or maybe by an entirely different reference scheme, such as is used for local SVG references:

[**`/inline-id.html`**](https://795258201.glitch.me/inline-id.html)

```html
<script type="module" id="example">
  export function example() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
  };
</script>
<script type="module">
  import {example} from '#example';

  example();
</script>
```

But neither of these hypotheticals actually work, and I haven't seen an alternative which does.

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to accomplish this -- potentially using Service Workers?

Comment: I don't think that homebrew non-spec compliant `inline-module` can be considered a good start with ES modules. Webpack/Rollup bundles are still indispensable in production - *especially* if you're afraid of blocking requests. Yes, service worker looks like a viable solution - but it still should make requests in order to provide data... which can be blocking, btw.

Comment: @estus I was imagining using service workers to take the inlined `<script>` tags and use them to populate the cache, to avoid the additional requests. These could perhaps even use the standard `type="module"` with an added body, if the implementation is clever enough.

Comment: I might be the only one who likes those _name tags_ for the code snippets.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Have you tried embedding external scripts as data-uris?

Answer (score 49):

## Hacking Together Our Own `import from '#id'`

Exports/imports between inline scripts aren't natively supported, but it was a fun exercise to hack together an implementation for my documents. Code-golfed down to a small block, I use it like this:

```html
<script type="module" data-info="https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834063">let l,e,t
='script',p=/(from\s+|import\s+)['"](#[\w\-]+)['"]/g,x='textContent',d=document,
s,o;for(o of d.querySelectorAll(t+'[type=inline-module]'))l=d.createElement(t),o
.id?l.id=o.id:0,l.type='module',l[x]=o[x].replace(p,(u,a,z)=>(e=d.querySelector(
t+z+'[type=module][src]'))?a+`/* ${z} */'${e.src}'`:u),l.src=URL.createObjectURL
(new Blob([l[x]],{type:'application/java'+t})),o.replaceWith(l)//inline</script>

<script type="inline-module" id="utils">
  let n = 1;
  
  export const log = message => {
    const output = document.createElement('pre');
    output.textContent = `[${n++}] ${message}`;
    document.body.appendChild(output);
  };
</script>

<script type="inline-module" id="dogs">
  import {log} from '#utils';
  
  log("Exporting dog names.");
  
  export const names = ["Kayla", "Bentley", "Gilligan"];
</script>

<script type="inline-module">
  import {log} from '#utils';
  import {names as dogNames} from '#dogs';
  
  log(`Imported dog names: ${dogNames.join(", ")}.`);
</script>
```

Instead of `<script type="module">`, we need to define our script elements using a custom type like `<script type="inline-module">`. This prevents the browser from trying to execute their contents itself, leaving them for us to handle. The script (full version below) finds all `inline-module` script elements in the document, and transforms them into regular script module elements with the behaviour we want.

Inline scripts can't be directly imported from each other, so we need to give the scripts importable URLs. We generate a `blob:` URL for each of them, containing their code, and set the `src` attribute to run from that URL instead of running inline. The `blob:` URLs acts like normal URLs from the server, so they can be imported from other modules. Each time we see a subsequent `inline-module` trying to import from `'#example'`, where `example` is the ID of a `inline-module` we've transformed, we modify that import to import from the `blob:` URL instead. This maintains the one-time execution and reference deduplication that modules are supposed to have.

```html
<script type="module" id="dogs" src="blob:https://example.com/9dc17f20-04ab-44cd-906e">
  import {log} from /* #utils */ 'blob:https://example.com/88fd6f1e-fdf4-4920-9a3b';

  log("Exporting dog names.");

  export const names = ["Kayla", "Bentley", "Gilligan"];
</script>
```

The execution of module script elements is always deferred until after the document is parsed, so we don't need to worry about trying to support the way that traditional script elements can modify the document while it's still being parsed.

```js
export {};

for (const original of document.querySelectorAll('script[type=inline-module]')) {
  const replacement = document.createElement('script');

  // Preserve the ID so the element can be selected for import.
  if (original.id) {
    replacement.id = original.id;
  }

  replacement.type = 'module';

  const transformedSource = original.textContent.replace(
    // Find anything that looks like an import from '#some-id'.
    /(from\s+|import\s+)['"](#[\w\-]+)['"]/g,
    (unmodified, action, selector) => {
      // If we can find a suitable script with that id...
      const refEl = document.querySelector('script[type=module][src]' + selector);
      return refEl ?
        // ..then update the import to use that script's src URL instead.
        `${action}/* ${selector} */ '${refEl.src}'` :
        unmodified;
    });

  // Include the updated code in the src attribute as a blob URL that can be re-imported.
  replacement.src = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([transformedSource], {type: 'application/javascript'}));

  // Insert the updated code inline, for debugging (it will be ignored).
  replacement.textContent = transformedSource;

  original.replaceWith(replacement);
}
```

*Warnings:* this simple implementation doesn't handle script elements added after the initial document has been parsed, or allow script elements to import from other script elements that occur after them in the document. If you have both `module` and `inline-module` script elements in a document, their relative execution order may not be correct. The source code transformation is performed using a crude regex that won't handle some edge cases such as periods in IDs.

Comment: You can further golf the regex to `/(from|import)\s+('|")(#[\w\-]+)\2/g`

Comment: Do you have that in github or npm?

Comment: I wonder if that's possible with extended custom element like `<script is="inline-module" type="module" id="a"></script>`

Comment: I resolved the "no periods" issue by using this query selector:

`const refEl = document.querySelector(\`script[type=module][src][id="${selector}"]\`);`

I also made the selector looked for more generic:

`/(from\s+|import\s+)['"](.*)['"]/g`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the page with inline modules is loaded with Pupeteer for some reason

Answer (score 15):

This is possible with service workers.

Since a service worker should be installed before it will be able to process a page, this requires to have a separate page to initialize a worker to avoid chicken/egg problem - or a page can reloaded when a worker is ready.

## Example

Here's a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sun2hq3D5CLWrNflh6ek?p=info) that is supposed to be workable in modern browsers that support native ES modules and `async..await` (namely Chrome):

*index.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      (async () => {
        try {
          const swInstalled = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('./');

          await navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', { scope: './' })

          if (!swInstalled) {
            location.reload();
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Worker not registered', err);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    World,

    <script type="module" data-name="./example.js">
      export function example() {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
      };
    </script>

    <script type="module">
      import {example} from './example.js';

      example();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*sw.js*

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  // parsed pages
  if (/^https:\/\/run.plnkr.co\/\w+\/$/.test(e.request.url)) {
    e.respondWith(parseResponse(e.request));
  // module files
  } else if (cachedModules.has(e.request.url)) {
    const moduleBody = cachedModules.get(e.request.url);
    const response = new Response(moduleBody,
      { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'text/javascript' }) }
    );
    e.respondWith(response);
  } else {
    e.respondWith(fetch(e.request));
  }
});

const cachedModules = new Map();

async function parseResponse(request) {
  const response = await fetch(request);
  if (!response.body)
    return response;

  const html = await response.text(); // HTML response can be modified further
  const moduleRegex = /<script type="module" data-name="([\w./]+)">([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/;
  const moduleScripts = html.match(new RegExp(moduleRegex.source, 'g'))
    .map(moduleScript => moduleScript.match(moduleRegex));

  for (const [, moduleName, moduleBody] of moduleScripts) {
    const moduleUrl = new URL(moduleName, request.url).href;
    cachedModules.set(moduleUrl, moduleBody);
  }
  const parsedResponse = new Response(html, response);
  return parsedResponse;
}
```

Script bodies are being cached (native `Cache` can be used as well) and returned for respective module requests.

### Concerns

- The approach is inferior to the application built and chunked with bundling tool like Webpack or Rollup in terms of performance, flexibility, solidity and browser support - especially if blocking concurrent requests are the primary concern.
- Inline scripts increase bandwidth usage. This is naturally avoided when scripts are loaded once and cached by the browser.
- Inline scripts aren't modular and contradict the concept of ECMAScript modules (unless they are generated from real modules by server-side template).
- Service worker initialization should be performed on a separate page to avoid unnecessary requests.
- The solution is limited to a single page and doesn't take `<base>` into account.
- A regular expression is used for demonstration purposes only. When used like in the example above **it enables the execution of arbitrary JavaScript code** that is available on the page. A proven library like `parse5` should be used instead (it will result in performance overhead, and still, there may be security concerns). **Never use regular expressions to parse the DOM**.

Comment: I love it! Very clever.

Comment: This would be even more gross, so I probably don't recommend it, but if we're rewriting index.html then that gives us a way to synchronously detect whether the service worker was loaded, by having it add some attribute to the page, and so prevent anything else from loading/running inappropriately the first time, instead of waiting for the async getRegistration result.

Comment: Yes. `location.reload()` doesn't smell good but demonstrates the issue. Generally I would recommend to have separate server responses for `/` and `/?serviceWorkerInstalledOrNotSupported` entry points.

Comment: How do you install a service worker? These are delivered over HTTP.

Comment: @Melab Can you clarify? The installation is done in `<script>`.

Answer (score 4):

I tweaked [Jeremy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834063/13052533) answer with the use of [this article to prevent scripts from executing](https://medium.com/snips-ai/how-to-block-third-party-scripts-with-a-few-lines-of-javascript-f0b08b9c4c0)

```
<script data-info="https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834063">
// awsome guy on [data-info] wrote 90% of this but I added the mutation/module-type part

let l,e,t='script',p=/(from\s+|import\s+)['"](#[\w\-]+)['"]/g,x='textContent',d=document,s,o;

let evls = event => (
  event.target.type === 'javascript/blocked', 
  event.preventDefault(),
  event.target.removeEventListener( 'beforescriptexecute', evls ) )

;(new MutationObserver( mutations => 
  mutations.forEach( ({ addedNodes }) => 
    addedNodes.forEach( node => 
      ( node.nodeType === 1 && node.matches( t+'[module-type=inline]' )
      && ( 
        node.type = 'javascript/blocked',
        node.addEventListener( 'beforescriptexecute', evls ),
      
        o = node,
        l=d.createElement(t),
        o.id?l.id=o.id:0,
        l.type='module',
        l[x]=o[x].replace(p,(u,a,z)=>
          (e=d.querySelector(t+z+'[type=module][src]'))
            ?a+`/* ${z} */'${e.src}'`
            :u),
        l.src=URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([l[x]],
          {type:'application/java'+t})),
        o.replaceWith(l)
      )//inline

) ) )))
.observe( document.documentElement, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
} )

// for(o of d.querySelectorAll(t+'[module-type=inline]'))
//   l=d.createElement(t),
//   o.id?l.id=o.id:0,
//   l.type='module',
//   l[x]=o[x].replace(p,(u,a,z)=>
//     (e=d.querySelector(t+z+'[type=module][src]'))
//       ?a+`/* ${z} */'${e.src}'`
//       :u),
//   l.src=URL.createObjectURL(
//     new Blob([l[x]],
//     {type:'application/java'+t})),
//   o.replaceWith(l)//inline</script>
```

I'm hoping that this solves the dynamic-script-appending issue (using MutationObserver), vs-code not syntax-highlighting (preserving type=module) and I imagine that using the same MutationObserver one could execute scripts once the imported ids are added to the DOM.

Please tell me if this has issues!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that's possible.

For inline scripts you're stuck with one of the more traditional ways of modularizing code, like the namespacing you demonstrated using object literals.

With [webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) you can do [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) which you could use to grab a very minimal chunk of code on page load and then incrementally grab the rest as needed. Webpack also has the advantage of allowing you to use the module syntax (plus a ton of other ES201X improvements) in way more environments than just Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 2):

We can use blob and importmap to import inline scripts.

https://github.com/xitu/inline-module

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="inline-module" id="foo">
  const foo = 'bar';
  export {foo};
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/inline-module/index.js" setup></script>
<script type="module">
  import {foo} from '#foo';
  app.textContent = foo;
</script>
```