# while using npm start in the terminal of visual studio I get an error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using JavaScipt ES6 with Node. I am using visual studio code.  I am getting this error when I run npm start:
The error is:

```
×  C:\Users\markp\source\repos\bioinvisionTest\index.html:1:31: Imports and requires are not supported inside inline <script> tags yet
```

in other programs the import works.  This one it doesn't.  All that is in the program is this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>    
  <script>
    import TestComponent from "./components/Testcomponent"
  </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

and in the components folder there is file called Testcomponent js that contains this:

```
function TestComponent() {
  console.log("test component js")
}

export default {
  TestComponent
}
```

Comment: Welcome!  The error is telling you that you cannot put an `import` statement in an inline script.  You need to put it within another .js file.

Comment: so do not use an inline script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inlining ECMAScript Modules in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817297/inlining-ecmascript-modules-in-html)

Comment: I took it out of inline script and that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

return key is somting which you can't simply ignore if it's multiline codes.

If you are uinsg Creaet-react-app as generator then i will recommend use APP.js as base and inject your component in that file for now. Later you can redesign .

If you are using only HTML and JS file then you should import react and react-dom library in your index.html file .

One page React App , place in your html file.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
class Greeting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<p>Hello world</p>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modules are natively suppported 
[refer MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Try adding `type="module"` to your script tag.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>

  <script type="module">
  import TestComponent from "./components/Testcomponent"




  </script> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried this  <script type="module"> and it still is getting the same error.