# Transform javascript string with `import` statement into a function in the browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I will like my vue application to transform the following string:

```
const test = 'import { pi } from "MathPie"; function test() { console.log(pi); } export default test;'
```

into a function that I could call.

```js
import { pi } from "MathPie";

function test() {
  console.log(pi);
}

export default test;
```

I already tried using `eval` (even if it's evil), but it doens't work because `import` statement aren't supported by it.

```
eval(test)()
> Cannot use import statement outside a module
> Should log '3.14159'
```

*The snippet is for presentation only, I'm aware of Math.PI*

My question is how I can evaluate a string with `import` statement?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: why would you want to evaluate an arbitrary string?

Comment: Generally, you can't use module exports outside of a module unless at least one of those module exposes the exports to the global scope (e.g.: `window.test = test;`). Generally, you can't `import` inlined modules so injecting a string as an inline module doesn't really get you anywhere (though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834063/367865) might offer a path forward).

Comment: You can't do that. `MathPie` is likely NPM package, while a browser is clueless about node_modules, native ESM support can't handle them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can use a combination of [dynamic import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) together with [createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

A test example is below:

```js
(async() => { // <= if you don't support top level await.
  const jsCode = `
export default function defaultTest() { console.log('this is default test func'); };
export function primaryTest() { console.log('this is primary test func'); };
export function secondaryTest() { console.log('this is secondary test func'); };`;

  const blobData = new Blob([jsCode], {
    type: 'text/javascript'
  });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
  const {
    "default": defaultTest,
    primaryTest,
    secondaryTest
  } = await import(url);
  
  defaultTest();
  primaryTest();
  secondaryTest();
})()
```