# use a function declared from a separate <script> tag in the same page that uses module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

we have this code

```
 <script type="module">
        function foo1()
        {
            console.log("Ray cast is called");
        }
    </script>
    <script >
         foo1();
    </script>
```

we get the error that foo1 is not defined.
Note that the first  tag needed to be a module as it will be importing 3rd party library and they are using module.
The above code is already stripped down for simplicity.

I think the work around for this one is just to write the foo1() in a separate file and just import it so I can use it? or is there another way?

Comment: I'd make the second script a module as well, and import from the first. (This involves making them non-inline, but that's usually for the best anyway.)

Comment: how to import from the second script given that its a script tag and not a file?

Comment: See my comment: *"(This involves making them non-inline, but that's usually for the best anyway.)"*

Comment: @user2300947 you can't [(not natively, anyway)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817297/inlining-ecmascript-modules-in-html). Only the the script that imports from other scripts can be inline. An inline script cannot export due to that the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement needs a reference to a module.