# Can we import from exports in HTML <script type=module>?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

This is a valid syntax.

```
<script id="test" type="module">
    const a = 42;
    export default a;
</script>
```

How do we get back the `a` value from this script module?

### What I've Tried

```
<script type="module">
    import a from './current.html#test';
    // import a from '.#test';
    console.log(a);
</script>
```

### Use Cases

If you ask about use cases,

1. Suppose we have separate fragment of HTML that sent at separate time. There should be communication around them.
2. We want to make a documentation, and make the code snippet runs. It has one generic engine, in which each code snippet will sent parameters (no, not just primitive data) to it. This export is the parameter.

Comment: See [Inlining ECMAScript Modules in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817297/inlining-ecmascript-modules-in-html).

Comment: You have to see how to inline script modules as above comment says or why not create a `var` variable for a global context?

Comment: That's good to see solutions. I thought, the standards has figure the way of this, because they allow such inline module syntax.