# Can i get the variables declared in HTML script tag to the script.js

Tags: javascript

Can i get the variables declared in HTML script tag to the source file script.js and link both in if module

HTML

```
<script type="module" src="script.js">
 let mystatement = '34'
</script>
```

In script.js

```
console.log(mystatement)
```

or link both files.

HTML

```
<script type="module" src="script.js">
 myfun(7)
</script>
```

In script.js

```
let myfun = (a) =>{ return a}
console.log(mystatement)
```

Comment: with `type="module"` you need to use export/import

Comment: yes i know have done

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817297/inlining-ecmascript-modules-in-html

Comment: `have done` , except there's no import or export in the code you posted, so ... more like "have not done"