Is it possible to export a self-invoking function as a namespace?
I'm trying to define the namespace in one file as:
let editor = (()=>{
    var editorVisible = false;
    var toggleEditor = ()=>{};
    var initEditor = ()=>{};
})();
export default editor;

and import it in another:
import {editor} from '@src/components/editor';
console.log(editor); //<= undefined

But whatever I do, it's always undefined although compiled by webpack without errors.
UPD I see from the comments that my function doesn't return anything. But you guys suggest returning every single element of it. How to return the whole namespace without returning every single function or variable of it?
UPD2 After import, I want to use the editor in the following way:
editor.initEditor();


Well your function does return undefined...

"I'm trying to define the namespace in one file" - really you should just use named exports. export var editorVisible = false; export var toggleEditor = ()=>{}; export var initEditor = ()=>{};, then import * as editor from '…'.

Or -- let editor = (() => {   const resetStuff = () => {     var editorVisible = false;     var toggleEditor = () => {};     var initEditor = () => {};   };   resetStuff();   return resetStuff; })(); export default editor;

You need return {editorVisible, toggleEditor, initEditor} at the end of the IIFE.

@Barmar I don't want to return variables and inner functions separately, I want to return the whole namespace, how can I achieve it?

That's what this does, by putting them into an object. The object is the namespace.

The key is "one file". So your module file essentially is a namespace so you don't need IIFE, just use a regular module with named exports:
export var editorVisible = false;
export var toggleEditor = ()=>{};
export var initEditor = ()=>{};



<script type="module" data-info="https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834063">let l,e,t
='script',p=/(from\s+|import\s+)['"](#[\w\-]+)['"]/g,x='textContent',d=document,
s,o;for(o of d.querySelectorAll(t+'[type=inline-module]'))l=d.createElement(t),o
.id?l.id=o.id:0,l.type='module',l[x]=o[x].replace(p,(u,a,z)=>(e=d.querySelector(
t+z+'[type=module][src]'))?a+`/* ${z} */'${e.src}'`:u),l.src=URL.createObjectURL
(new Blob([l[x]],{type:'application/java'+t})),o.replaceWith(l)//inline</script>

<script type="inline-module" id="editor">
  export var editorVisible = false;
  export var toggleEditor = ()=>{};
  export var initEditor = ()=>{};
</script>

<script type="inline-module">
  import * as editor from '#editor';
  console.log(editor);
</script>



